# In an iOS 5 Storyboard, how do you push a new scene to the original view controller from a Popover?

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, ios5, storyboard

I'm creating a popoverSegue from a new view controller and want to push a third view controller onto the original stack.  This is how I'm creating the application:

1. Create a new `Single View Application`
2. Select `Use Storyboards`
3. Select the `MainStoryboard.storyboard` file.
4. Select the only View Controller, change the `Title` and `Identifier` to `initialView`, then select `Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller`
5. Drag two new `View Controller` objects from the Objects Library onto the canvas
6. Change the `Title` and `Identifier` of the new View Controllers to: `popoverView` and `newView`.
7. Add a `Round Rect Button` object from the Object Library to `initialView` and `popoverView`.
8. Add a `Label` object from the Object Library to `newView.
9. Control click the button in the `initialView` and drag to `popoverView`.
10. Select the `Popover` option from the `Storyboard Segues` menu that appears.
11. Control click the button in the `popoverView` and drag to the `newView`.
12. Select the `Push` option fromt the `Storyboard Segues` menu.
13. Build & Run.

Click the first button, and the popover appears, but when you click the button within the popover, nothing happens (it should push the new view but doesn't.)

What I **want** to do is for it to push onto the `Navigation Controller` stack, but am not sure how to setup the storyboard for that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You're expecting the `UINavigationController` hierarchy to extend itself into a presented popover. It won't. The same goes for presenting modal view controllers. If you were to log `self.navigationController` in `popoverView`, you would see that it is nil.

Embed `popoverView` into it's own `UINavigationController`. Remember that if you're overriding `prepareForSegue:sender:` and attempting to configure the popover, you will need to get the `topViewController` from `destinationViewController` as the destination is now an instance of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: your explanation just helped me solve my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591559/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-popover-view-controller-inside-a-navigation-controll). Thank you

Comment: could you please add a small example of that?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it should work, but if it doesn't try the following:
1. Click the segue that doesn't work and give it an identifier. Let's say it's  PopoverToNewSegue.

1. In your implementation file for the popover view controller, add an action when the button is clicked.
2. That function should return void and add the following line:
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PopoverToNewSegue" sender:self];

That should get your segue running. I've noticed that segues don't always work like you expect them to, but this one works for me without fail.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I tried to call performSegueWithIdentifier like you said and it did nothing :(